# Integração entre R e Java

Tags: java, r, java-ee

Estou trabalhando em um projeto e tenho que integrar a linguagem `R` com `Java`.
Poderiam me ajudar indicando um boa biblioteca ou um código (*Hello World*) que faça essa integração?

Comment: Conseguiu fazer a integração?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7455788/747891):

O usuário que respondeu a pergunta já conseguiu fazer a integração com sucesso usando duas alternativas.

**[JRI](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/):**

- **Vantagem**: provavelmente tem melhor performance.
- **Desvantagem**: você precisa configurar algumas variáveis de ambiente e bibliotecas diferentes em Windows e Unix.

**[RServe](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/):**

- **Vantagem**: fácil de configurar, não precisa inicializar o R nem *linkar* nenhuma biblioteca R, pode ser executado em máquinas diferentes.
- **Desvantagem**: baseado em TCP/IP (um servidor precisa estar executando), não tem callbacks do R.

**Outra alternativa** que ele nunca usou: [RCaller](http://code.google.com/p/rcaller/)